# Get images from kwikee api

Tags: api

How to integrate Kwikee API to get the product images or other information?
I  have found the documentation on the link. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Fm768c3PnSaBDAx1F5tjZiJkhaWzKsb13y2lbOtljhk/edit#. Here is I follow the endpoint https://api.kwikeesystems.com/v1.0/init/xml, clicking on this ask for user-name and password when I fill the user-name and password it gives me an error

"Authorization Required
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required." Although I fill the correct user-name and password.